# Why isn't default or value initialization more common for aggregates?

Tags: c++

I believe since C++14, the brace-or-equal initialization became available in standard. I try to always initialize my data to avoid any surprises, and extend that practice to initializing my aggregates, i.e.,

```cpp
struct bar {
   int a = 0;
   int c = 1;
   double b = 2.3;
};
```

I hardly ever see anyone else do this. It's my understanding that this preserves the aggregate layout and the struct will just default-initialize members that you do not value-initialize or assign. I'm wondering if maybe I'm doing something wrong since I don't see others do this. Am I misunderstanding something or overlooking potential problems this introduces?

**Edit:** Thanks for the replies. In my above example, it may be an aggregate containing tuning parameters for some system, where `double b = 2.3` may indeed make sense. I understand that a constructor can do this as well, so I suppose my question really boils down to: What difference is there between the default-initialization scheme I have above vs. a constructor?

Comment: These are called "default member initializers" and exist since C++11. But only since C++14 do they not prevent a class from being an aggregate. In your example, how much sense does it really make for e.g. `b` to default to `2.3`? Would it generally not be a bug to create a `bar` and not explicitly give `b` a value?

Comment: With C++, we _don't want to pay for what we don't use_. Your initialization may be unnecessary in some situations and you don't want a program to spent time with it. Simple use case: setting values of a large array in parallel. You don't want to initialize objects first to default values if they will be then assigned some new values in a parallel section.

Comment: @DanielLangr Then allocate raw memory and call construct_at in a parallel section.

Comment: @user17732522 While `2.3` might be an odd number to set this is just an example and it might be that `2.3` is exactly what the default value should be and not `0`. It's very easy to miss setting `b` when code grows over time. Say you started out with a `bar` that only had `a` and `c`. Then when you add `b` you give it a default value so all the places that `bar x{0, 1};` will get a sensible `b`. If you really want `bar` to always be initialized with all members than write a constructor that requires them instead of aggregate initialization.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Sure it's possible. But raw memory allocation and placement new (`construct_at`) are low level stuff rarely used by application programmers (even not recommended for them).

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Agreed. I hoped OP would answer so that "_I try to always_" might be dissected a bit more. If there is a sensible default value, that's fine, but it sounds like OP is doing this regardless of that always.

Comment: Might be a canary that is easy to recognize when debugging. 0,1,2.3 is probably unlikely to happen for correct initializations.

Comment: I definitely see an advantage of NOT being able to just add a new member with a default value, as this would make me deal with possible side-effects during runtime instead of compile-time. Also, having a ctor means you have a dtor ;)